# Get Dynamic checklist values from controller to blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I m trying to send check list values from one blade to another blade through a controller it display in dd()  but when i try to fetch in blade it gives an error

```
foreach ($modem_details as $list) {
<input type="checkbox" id="modem_Id_' . $list->id . '"name="changed_modem" value=" '. $list->id .'">
```

[here is the snapshot of dd()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40TwI.png)

here is error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdMpu.png)

Comment: i don't think it's related to the dd, can you share more code?

Comment: I just want to separate these changemodem()id so i perform DB operation based on these ids. For Now  i receive with dynamic values with id .

Comment: For example if a fetch data based on these id i dont know how i use in query

Comment: still need more code

Comment: Thank you jack for respond but my issue is solved By adding a little brackets "[]" with check box . i try to fetch data by its dynamic content which works fine but i m nota able to send these dynamic data so i change my approach and get all data all in once. well Thank you for time and concerns!..